# How to dynamically generate choices with 'getChoices' member function in Buildbot?

Tags: python, buildbot

I already have a method that returns a list of branches of a specific repo and I would like to use it to dynamically generate choices based on the returned list in the web UI of Buildbot.

For example, instead of this static list:

```
c['schedulers'].append(
    schedulers.ForceScheduler(
        ...,
        branch=util.ChoiceStringParameter(
            ...,
            choices=['master', 'branch1', 'branch2', ...],
            ...
```

I would like something dynamically generated, like this one:

```
def get_branches():
    refs = subprocess.check_output(["git", "ls-remote", "--heads", "git@bitbucket.org:foo/bar.git"])
    branches = []
    for item in refs.split('\n'):
        m = re.match(r"^\w+\trefs/heads/(.*$)", item)
        if m:
            branch = m.group(1)
            branches.append(branch)

    return branches

c['schedulers'].append(
    schedulers.ForceScheduler(
        ...,
        branch=util.ChoiceStringParameter(
            ...,
            choices=get_branches,
            ...
```

The Buildbot documentation explains that it can be done via subclassing and overiding the 'getChoices' member function. It also gives [an example](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-schedulers.html?highlight=getchoices#inheritbuildparameter) provided by the source for the InheritBuildParameter class but I don't understand how to use the 'getChoices' member function.

There is so little documentation about this subject that I'm compelled to ask you this question! Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using a class that is a generator is one way to make the choices dynamic:

```
class Branches(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.branches = []
        refs = subprocess.check_output(["git", "ls-remote", "--heads", "git@bitbucket.org:foo/bar.git"])
        for item in refs.split('\n'):
            m = re.match(r"^\w+\trefs/heads/(.*)$", item)
            if m:
                branch = m.group(1)
                self.branches.append(branch)
    def __iter__(self):
        self.__init__()
        for b in self.branches:
            yield b

c['schedulers'].append( ForceScheduler(
        ...
        branch=ChoiceStringParameter(name="branch",
                                 choices=Branches(),
                                 default="develop"),
       ...
```